# Column-style bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, columns

A problem that's been annoying me for years (http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-04/msg01387.html) has been how to create a column'ed bibliography. E.g., take a look at the bibliography in:

http://www.cgd.ucar.edu/staff/trenbert/trenberth.papers/UppalaERA05.pdf

[image]

That's what I want! Ideally, I'd like four columns (Author, Year, Journal/Source, Title+Pages) rather than the three shown in the example (although that's a start).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Do you want to use `biblatex`? Or what do you use?

Comment: Yes, my first choice would be biblatex.

Comment: OK, I've unearthed a .cls file which will definitely produce the three-columned bibliography:

http://homepages.see.leeds.ac.uk/~lecrrb/05192/qjrms2.cls .

Now I'd want to figure out how to extract the parts necessary for just the columns.

Answer (score 7):

This is just an idea and should be expanded according to your needs, of course. I used the `xpatch` package.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\prebiba}{%
  \par\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{7em}p{2em}X}
    \usebibmacro{author}
    & \printdate
    & \clearname{author}\clearfield{year}}
\newcommand{\prebibe}{%
  \par\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{7em}p{2em}X}
    \usebibmacro{editor+others}
    & \printdate
    & \clearname{editor}\clearfield{year}}
\newcommand{\patchdrivers}{%
  \xpretobibdriver{article}{\prebiba}{}{}%
  \xapptobibdriver{article}{\end{tabularx}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibdriver{book}{\prebiba}{}{}%
  \xapptobibdriver{book}{\end{tabularx}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibdriver{incollection}{\prebiba}{}{}%
  \xapptobibdriver{incollection}{\end{tabularx}}{}{}%
  \xpretobibdriver{collection}{\prebibe}{}{}%
  \xapptobibdriver{collection}{\end{tabularx}}{}{}%
}
\defbibenvironment{tablebib}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{}%
    \patchdrivers}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space,sigfridsson,piccato,matuz:doody}%
\printbibliography[env=tablebib]%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oleg, many thanks; that does seem to achieve the desired result.  Could you also post a link to the bib file? When I try to use your code with my own bib, I'm not getting the table, just everything in one line, and no carriage return between references either.

Comment: You probably need to add the `\par` command, see my correction of the code. I also replaced `tabu` with a less "exotic" `tabularx`.
The bib file is actually from the `biblatex` distribution: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib.

Comment: Certainly, it would be better to use the `longtable` package here, but unfortunately I couldn't cope with it. Perhaps someone else will.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce Oleg's example. As surmised, I'd want to expand this. An initial question: the method in the cls file I posted; that seems to allow the user to define what goes in the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns (line beginning \def\bib#1#2#3{% ). This tightly defines what goes in each column, but would need the bib file to be written in this custom format. Oleg's method handles a normal bib, but would it need each entry type to be programmed similar to what he's done for the 4 types so far. Is this thinking correct?

Answer (score 7):

This is another approach, which doesn't require patching bib drivers. 
The code is quite long but the structure is clear, I think.

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\ppno\ppspace}
         {\pno\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \ifthenelse{ \iffieldundef{issue} \and \iffieldundef{date} }
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
      \iffieldundef{issue}
        {\usebibmacro{date}}
        {\printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \usebibmacro{date}}}%
    \newunit}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \par\textbf{${@}$\printfield{entrytype}}\hrulefill
  \par%
  \tabular{@{}p{.2\textwidth}p{.05\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}p{.3\textwidth}p{.15\textwidth}@{}}
    \raggedright\parindent=2em\hangindent=2em\noindent\baselineskip=9pt%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{article}
                  \or \ifentrytype{inbook}
                  \or \ifentrytype{incollection}
                  \or \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
                  }
      {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{book}
                  \or \ifentrytype{booklet}
                  \or \ifentrytype{misc}
                  \or \ifentrytype{online}
                  }
      {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{collection}
                  \or \ifentrytype{proceedings}
                  }
      {\usebibmacro{editor+others}}
      {}%
    \ifentrytype{manual}
      {\usebibmacro{author/editor}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{patent}
                  \or \ifentrytype{report}
                  \or \ifentrytype{thesis}
                  \or \ifentrytype{unpublished}
                  }
      {\usebibmacro{author}}
      {}%
    \ifentrytype{periodical}
      {\usebibmacro{editor}}
      {}
  & \raggedright\noindent\baselineskip=9pt\printfield{year}
  & \parindent=2em\hangindent=2em\noindent\baselineskip=9pt%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{pages}%
    \finentry
  & \parindent=2em\hangindent=2em\noindent\baselineskip=9pt%
    \renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}%
    \renewbibmacro*{title}{}%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{year}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{article}
                  \or \ifentrytype{inbook}
                  \or \ifentrytype{incollection}
                  \or \ifentrytype{inproceedings}
                  }
      {\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{book}
                  \or \ifentrytype{booklet}
                  \or \ifentrytype{misc}
                  \or \ifentrytype{online}
                  }
      {\renewbibmacro*{author/editor+others/translator+others}{}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{collection}
                  \or \ifentrytype{proceedings}
                  }
      {\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{}%
       \renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{}}
      {}%
    \ifentrytype{manual}
      {\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{}}
      {}%
    \ifthenelse{  \ifentrytype{patent}
                  \or \ifentrytype{report}
                  \or \ifentrytype{thesis}
                  \or \ifentrytype{unpublished}
                  }
      {\renewbibmacro*{author}{}}
      {}%
    \ifentrytype{periodical}
      {\renewbibmacro*{editor}{}%
       \renewbibmacro*{byeditor}{}}
      {}%
    \nopunct\bibsentence%
}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  & \usebibmacro{pageref}
  \endtabular
}

\defbibenvironment{tablebib}
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
  {}
  {}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\begin{document}
\cite{piccato}\cite{matuz:doody}\cite{westfahl:space}%\cite{murray}
\newpage\cite{matuz:doody}\cite{kant:kpv}\cite{ctan}
\newpage\cite{aksin}\cite{matuz:doody}\cite{moraux}
\newpage\cite{westfahl:space}\cite{ctan}%\cite{murray}\cite{gaonkar:in}
\cite{almendro} %patent
\cite{chiu} %report
\cite{geer} %thesis
\cite{jcg}  %periodical
\cite{cms} %manual
\newpage
\printbibliography[env=tablebib]%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ``\rm`` is a 2.09 command, I think `rmfamily` is the recommended way now. Also, you may want to add another column - OP wanted Journal /Source separate from Title/ pages.

Comment: Yes, sure. I just copied it from the .cls above. As for the additional column, this demands specific decisions concerning the style --- what is the Source, what to do with books (when Source and Title are the same) etc. The answer is just an idea which should be definitely adjusted.

Comment: In fact, it needs quite a lot of adjustments. For example, the macro in the first column might be something like `\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}`, it may depend on the entrytype, the year in the last column may be printed or not and so on. These are all style requirements which are difficult to decide in advance.

Comment: Whilst I can't write the code myself, I can definitely help in defining the requirements to flesh this out further, to make it as useful as possible. One basic additional requirement I'd like to see here is another column, right at the end, for backrefs. @OlegDomanov is that possible?

Comment: Sure, let's try to do this (I also need something similar :). Could you then provide some additional information:
1) What biblatex style suits you needs best? Is it a standard style, APA or whatever? (It's better to modify a proper style from the very beginning).
2) So, you need 5 columns: Author/Editor, Year (or full date?), Title+Page, Journal/Source, Backref. Right?

Comment: 3) In the example you provided when the author is absent the editor is printed. When the editor is absent as well, nothing is printed, just a space. Is this correct?
4) Sometimes an organisation is printed in the first column. What is its field in the database, is it author, organisation, editor?
5) You differentiate between Source and Title. In case of books, collections, proceedings cited as a whole should we print their title as Source or as Title?

Comment: Great: I'm glad we can work to produce what should be (I hope) a widely useful solution. Before we get into the logic tree of how the content for each column is chosen, I'm wondering whether it's possible to cut that Gordian knot thus: is it possible to define hooks for each column? I.e., if for one bibentry, I want the author in Column 1, but for another, I want the institution, is there any code snippet which wouldn't harm the bib syntax, yet be picked up by your solution to identify which field goes into which column? That way, we wouldn't have to think out most/all possible scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by hooks, but yes, there is a macro `\ifentrytype` which you can use to check the type of the current entry.

Comment: I'm thinking more along the lines of `@article{Article1, author="Smith", year=2013, title="LaTeX", journal="MagazineX", col1=author, col2=year, col3=title,journal}` and `@article{Article2, editor="Jones", year=2012, title="TeX", journal="MagazineY", col1=editor, col2=year, col3=title,journal}`. I.e., leaving it down to the user to choose what goes into each column if certain basic defaults aren't desired.

Comment: It is possible, but is it necessary? If you have a style, this should be defined by the style. To hand this over to the user is hardly a good idea. I edited the answer, you can see how it may look for the standard `biblatex` style (I also printed the entrytypes just for information, they should be removed later, of course).

Comment: Agreed: and the current implementation looks fantastic. I actually quite like the ruled lines demarcating each entry. I'm just wondering how it would deal with, e.g., a page from the internet where the only the url, date visited (no actual publication date known), article title and institution name would be present? Or a report where there was an institution/organisation but no author or editor? That's why I was veering towards (optional) use of user hooks to force placement in the requisite column.

Comment: Well, I tried to avoid creating a new style but it's becoming messy. So I made finally a new style `biblatex-columnar` and put it on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/odomanov/biblatex-columnar). It's based on the `authoryear` style. Please check a compiled [test](https://bitbucket.org/odomanov/biblatex-columnar/downloads/test.pdf). As for your questions, biblatex is quite powerful and has a number of means to regulate the output on a per entry basis. I think we need to see if they are enough for your particular needs (I hope so). I doubt that a general solution is possible.

Comment: As for institution/organisation, biblatex manual recommends (2.3.3) using the `author`/`editor`/`shortauthor`/`shorteditor` fields for corporate names. Is this what you need? I added few entries as examples, please check them in the test PDF above.